# Android: Alert Dialog using DialogFragment is not showing up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a Alert Dialog but it doesn't show it and continues to process the next line of code. I've thoroughly searched but couldn't get any answer to this.

This is my fragment which is quite simple

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

  public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
    AlertDialogFragment frag = new AlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            ./*setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_dart_icon)
            .*/setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton("Close",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    })
            ./*setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    }).*/create();
  }
}
```

Code in my activity to display the dialog, but it skips it and moves onto the next line without displaying the dialog pop-up

```
DialogFragment alertDialogFragment = AlertDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(R.string.alert_dialog_title);
alertDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

/**
 * Forward to next Activity
 */
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectResponsibilityActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Not sure where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you opening a Dialog **and** starting a new activity? The current activity will try to show the dialog, but even if it does, the second activity will come onto the screen, so the dialog will not be visible.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't show up? Maybe, immediately after you show it, you start another activity. If you want it to stay, try showing it on the next activity.

Comment: Thanks guys, you pointed to the right direction and I now understand why it is not showing. My previous understanding was that it would display the dialog and wait for the user interaction to close it before proceeding to the forward. Basically this dialog is to display a error message to the user and I would like to reload the same activity instead of forwarding to the next one incase the dialog pops-up. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DialogFragment` is attached to its activity. When you start another activity, the activity your dialog fragment is attached is not visible anymore, so is your fragment.

Indirect implications are all over [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity))

-You can add a button to your `DialogFragment` and do this in its `onClick`

```
public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent())
}
```

-Or you can just reload the activity using the following code, without `onClick`, and show your dialogFragment in the new activity

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent())
```

of course you will have to set some flags or something like that before you start the new activity and check for that flag in your `onCreate()`. Only if it's set, then show your dialogfragment.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Now I understand how a fragment is tied to the activity. Removing the forward activity lines of code did the trick.